# How can I store a non-unicode string in the database of my Django App?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, geopy

I'm trying to access a field in views.py in order to perform an operation on it which will calculate its distance from a user-inputted point (using geopy). The input needs to be a plain string but is currently stored in my database as: u'(lat, lng)' which geopy does not enjoy.

How can I store the information in my db in the proper format ( ex. (lat, lng) ). The coordinates are originally inputted in this format.

Thank you in advance, apologies for not using proper terminology, new to this and self taught.

Answer (score 0):

Use django-annoying

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    lat_lng = JsonField()
```

And store:

```
MyModel.objects.create(lat_lng={'data': (lat, lng)}, ...)
```

And use:

```
my_model_object.lat_lng['data']
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the actual value stored in the table is `u'(lat, lng)'`?  Are you converting your string to another representation before storing it?  This doesn't look right.

If necessary, you can change the encoding the table uses.  Read about that here: [How to set the encoding for the tables' char columns in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198486/how-to-set-the-encoding-for-the-tables-char-columns-in-django)

Also you can `encode`/`decode` strings to a specific charset before using them in python: [What is the difference between encode/decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/whats-the-difference-between-encode-decode-python-2-x)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean "converting your string to antoher representation before storing it" sounds like that might be the case though.  Here's what I've got `class Place(models.Model):   coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=60)    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):      self.coordinates = Location(self.zipcode, self.street)      super(Venue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`  Then I try and access coordinates in views.py (for use in a method which calculates the distance between 2 sets of coordinates) but get u'(lat, lng) as my output