# Set default collation settings in django model

Tags: python, django

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings) says that default collation be 'utf8' but it isn't. Every time I run syncdb to create new tables the default collation of all character fields is 'latin1_swedish_ci'.

The same documentation also says

> Django doesn’t provide a way to set this on the model definition.

Is there any other way I can force django's syncdb to use a specific collation with character fields?

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198486/how-to-set-the-encoding-for-the-tables-char-columns-in-django

Comment: Thank you for providing this help. The suggestions are very helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

In general ( to change charset and collation ) you could use migrations, something like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.10
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('some_model', 'A_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE some_table CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;'),
    ]
```

Neverless the behaviour you are describing is weird, so maybe there are fancier ways to fix your particular issue.